# samba | cannot create file

Tags: linux, samba, file-permissions

I have CentOS7.1, samba-4.1.1 , users from ldap

I create share

```
[share]
        path= /path/to/share
        comment = Base
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        force group = DomainUsers
```

create file, set chmod/chown

```
mkdir -p /path/to/share
chmod 644 /path/to/share
chmod 644 /path/to/share/file.txt
chown user1:DomainUsers /path/to/share/file.txt
ls -l /path/to/share/file.txt

-rw-r--r-- 1 user1 DomainUsers 458 Jul 16 11:41 file.txt
```

Then, go to windows host, login as *user1* and try put few files to my share.

- View files.txt - OK
- Create newfiles/dir - Access denied
- Edit files.txt - Access denied

if chmod g+w /path/to/share/ (drwxr-xr-xm user1:DomainUsers) - create, edit, delete is fine, but my files can edit for any DomainUsers member. It's not good.

How make files writable for my only. DomainUsers for read only.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you need the following setup instead....

```
mkdir -p /path/to/share
chmod 755 /path/to/share
chmod 644 /path/to/share/file.txt
chown -R user1:DomainUsers /path/to/share
```

**Ensuring the directory has the correct access is just as important as the file.**
 - If the group has WRITE permissions to the directory then anybody can add or delete files.
 - This is true also if the individual file was not originally set up with no write access.
 - It could still be removed and then re-added as something else.